# Ruby, Recursion Method

Tags: ruby, recursion

I have a method that is basically a loop and it calls itself at the end each time. What is the best way for the method to not call itself when the date reaches a certain point? Each iteration through adds 1 day and basically processes stats for that day. It looks like the below:

```
def loop(start_day)
  date = start_day

  #do a bunch of stuff

  date = date +1.day

  if date > Time.now
    puts "loop should be over"
  end

  loop(date)
end
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but won't using recursion keep compounding the memory usage depending on the variables you are setting in `#do a bunch of stuff` whereas an `until` loop will clear out the variables with each loop?

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell It goes without saying (at least, I thought...) that this would be a silly thing to do in real life.  I assumed this was just an exercise.

Comment: Note that you do not need recursion in this scenario. You could create a range for the dates and then just iterate through each date of the range.

Comment: creating a range is more effective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Each iteration through adds 1 day

That's not true for the code you've posted. In your code you add 1 day to the start date *once* and then you keep processing the same date over and over again because you recurse on the old date (`start_date`), not the incremented date (`date`).

> What is the best way for the method to not call itself when the date reaches a certain point?

Just put the recursive call inside an `if` or, in this case, inside of the `else` of the `if` that you already have.

Answer (score 3):

Since you set `date` to `start_date` immediately, it seems there's no point in having both.  Here's the more canonical form of doing recursion:

```
def loop(date)
  return if date > Time.now
  #do a bunch of stuff
  loop(date + 1.day)
end
```

**Update:** If it's not obvious to you that recursion isn't necessary here, in real life, it would make more sense to do something like this:

```
def process_from(date)
  while date <= Time.now
    # Process date
    date += 1.day
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
def loop(start_day)
  return "loop should be over" if start_day >= Time.now
  #...
  loop(modified_date)
end
```

or...

```
def loop(start_day)
  date = start_day.dup
  time = Time.now
  date += 1.day while date <= time
  'loop should be over'
end
```

It seems like you want to iterate over all days from starting date to today. Then maybe this is even more simple:

```
def map_date(date)
  (date.to_date..Date.today).map do |d|
    d.strftime("Today is %A")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have base case (stop case) for recursive function;

example:

```
def loop(date)
    if date == certain_point
      return [something_for_stop]
    end

    loop(date - 1)
end
```